# How to sign in to Google Play Games from Android app (error 8)

Tags: java, android, google-play-games

I am trying to add saving games to Google Play Games cloud service to an existing android app but am getting error 8.

I was using [saved games support in android guide](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames) and [Collect all the stars 2 sample app](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples/tree/master/CollectAllTheStars2).

This is what I have tried so far:

### Console and Security Setup

Created game in game services. Saved Games is switched ON, all other features OFF.

Used "Linked Apps" and linked using debug SHA1 fingerprint.

Verified above in the Google API Console, all checks out and matches SHA1 hex string in console and using keytool.

```
keytool -list -keystore "C:\Users\dejan\.android\debug.keystore" -storepass android
```

Added myself as a tester and enabled testing for all environments.

### SDK manager

In Android Studio, used SDK tools to add "Google Play services"

### Android Manifest

Added the following to android manifest:

```
   <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
        android:value="@string/app_id" />
    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"/>
```

### In Android Main Activity

Added

```
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;
private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
// The currently signed in account, used to check the account has changed outside of this activity when resuming.
private GoogleSignInAccount mSignedInAccount = null;
```

In OnCreated method added:

```
   //initialize google play games
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
                // Since we are using SavedGames, we need to add the SCOPE_APPFOLDER to access Google Drive.
                .requestScopes(Drive.SCOPE_APPFOLDER)
                .build();
        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
```

For button click added:

```
startActivityForResult(mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent(), RC_SIGN_IN);
```

Finally, added onActivityResult

```
  @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {

        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(intent);

        try {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
            onConnected(account);
        } catch (ApiException apiException) {
            String message = String.format("%s (%s)", getString(R.string.signin_other_error), apiException.getStatusCode());
            mGoogleSignInError = true;
            Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(findViewById(R.id.mainContainerMenu), message, Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
            snackbar.show();

            onDisconnected();


        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

}
```

### Testing

I tried running the app from Android Studio to my physical device where I am logged in as a testing authorized user.

Also, tried making a signed apk through Android Studio and deploying it to device using adb command. When building apk, used debug key store and key.

In both cases I am getting error #8. Google Play splash screen is not showing, the screen just goes dark for a second and then I get an error.

### Logcat

> 2019-02-26 18:01:00.946 4892-7664/? E/Volley: [131] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 404 for https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2beta/apps/self?prettyPrint=false&fields=id
>
> 2019-02-26 16:15:29.365 1517-18694/? I/ActivityManager: START u0 {act=com.google.android.gms.auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN pkg=com.google.android.gms cmp=com.google.android.gms/.auth.api.signin.ui.SignInActivity (has extras)} from uid 10351 on display 0
>
> 2019-02-26 16:15:29.378 1517-31079/? E/ActivityManager: Sending non-protected broadcast com.motorola.motocare.INTENT_TRIGGER from system 4525:com.motorola.process.system/1000 pkg com.motorola.motgeofencesvc
>       java.lang.Throwable
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntentLocked(ActivityManagerService.java:18226)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerService.java:18826)
>           at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:512)
>           at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:2906)
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:565)

Am I missing some permissions in the manifest? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Tried adding various permissions, documnetation doesn;t say this is needed, but thought might help... It didn't     <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />

Comment: I have the same problem. Did not find any solution yet...

Comment: Nope, moved on to something else, will revisit soon